# Destruction of integrals of motion in chaotic systems: Fermi-Pasta-Ulam (FPU) paradox

Tags: classical-mechanics, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, complex-systems, integrals-of-motion

I am trying to understand behavior of system studied by Fermi, Pasta and Ulam i.e. chain of oscillators interacting via nonlinear forces. I am generally not very familiar with chaos theory and specifically, I have troubles understanding the role played by integrals of motion in such systems. If we consider FPU lattice which is governed by some Hamiltonian then the integral of motion, if I understand correctly, is some function on phase space which has vanishing Poisson bracket with the Hamiltonian itself. At the same time, sometimes (for example [here](http://www.jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_060_06_1116.pdf) I see something like that) the transition to chaotic behavior is described by "destruction" of integrals of motion. What is meant by that sentence? How is that possible since Poisson bracket vanishes?

I see similar thing in the case of the [Chirikov standard map](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Chirikov_standard_map) where the chaotic behavior appears when another invariant is destroyed. I would be thankful for any advice helping me to understand this problem.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.